# Change reply-to in evolution

Tags: evolution, gmail

I am getting in my inbox on gmail mail from multiple addresses. When I get e-mails in gmail I can choose reply-to address. Is there such a possibility in Evolution? I know that in the advanced settings, you can specify the return address for the account, but how to make sure that there was a list of multiple addresses and be able to choose just one? Or maybe there is a possibility that at once expose the return address for letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the message editor, you might have noticed that your "From" address is a drop-down box, letting you select from which account you want to send the mail. That's where you can do so.

In case you need additional "identities" there, I haven't found a convenient way to simply "configure a list" – but you can setup "dummy accounts" with no "inbound mail server" (i.e. setting "Server Type" to "None" for incoming), just configuring their "outgoing" (SMTP) settings. They will appear in the drop-down as well then.

As you requested more detailed instructions, here a short step-by-step:

- In *Evolution*, open the menu *Edit → Settings*
- *EMail Accounts* should already be selected. If not, do so.
- On the right hand side, push the "Add" button This starts the assistant.
- Hit "Next"
- Enter the name, mail address **<sup>1</sup>**, reply-to. Push "Next".
- Next screen is for where to *pull* mail from. In the "Server Type" drop-down on the very top, select "None". This will empty the form, and you can push the "Next" button again.
- On the next screen, enter the data for how mail using this "alias" should be sent. Use the SMTP settings for the account you chose for the "from" address (**<sup>1</sup>**).
- Again, push the "Next" button and verify your settings.
- If everything looks fine, one more "Next" creates the alias.

Now it should be available in the mail editor's drop down.